# Preencher valor em pagina na Internet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Entao pessoal to querendo colocar um valor numa pagina web, mas antes disso eu faço login nela e sou direcionado a outra pagina, lá eu navego até uma pagina diferente, e eu dei uma olhada no codigo da pagina e no local onde quero colocar a informação tem a parte nome, a principio seria igual a fazer o login na pagina, mas por algum motivo nao estou conseguindo colocar o valor nessa pagina.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim senha, usuario

sURL = "http://tx3.travian.com.br/" ' Navego até o site
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Espera a página carregar
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HtmlDoc = oBrowser.document

HtmlDoc.all.Name.Value = "" ' aqui coloco meu login
HtmlDoc.all.Password.Value = "" ' aqui coloco minha senha
HtmlDoc.all.lowRes.Click   ' clico em um botao
HtmlDoc.all.s1.Click      'click no botao de login

Do While oBrowser.Busy
DoEvents
Loop
oBrowser.navigate (sURL & ("build.php?tt=2&id=39"))    ' navego até a pagina que quero ir
Do While oBrowser.Busy
DoEvents
Loop
HtmlDoc.all.s4.Value = "4"      'É aqui o problema, quero colocar uma informacao aqui, é igual ao local onde boto minha senha e conta, mas por algum motivo dá erro. 
End Sub
```

O que poderia fazer aqui

Comment: Você dis que a última linha dá erro? Qual erro seria?

Answer (score 1):

Após as linhas

```
oBrowser.navigate (sURL & ("build.php?tt=2&id=39"))    ' navego até a pagina que quero ir
Do While oBrowser.Busy
DoEvents
```

você precisa carregar novamente o documento com:

```
Set HtmlDoc = oBrowser.document
```

Comment: O erro infelizmente continua. O erro diz que não aceita essa propriedade ou metodo.  Esse aqui é onde quero colocar `<input type="text" class="text" name="t4" value="" maxlength="6">`                                                       E é esse codigo é de onde coloca a conta `<input type="text" name="name" value="Bey" class="text">`

Answer (score 0):

Segue meu codigo apos a "mudança"

`Dim senha, usuario

sURL = "http://tx3.travian.com.br/" ' Navego até o site

Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer

oBrowser.Silent = True

oBrowser.navigate sURL

oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Espera a página carregar

Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document

HTMLDoc.all.Name.Value = "Bey" ' aqui coloco meu login

HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = "patrick10" ' aqui coloco minha senha

HTMLDoc.all.lowRes.Click   ' clico em um botao

HTMLDoc.all.s1.Click      'click no botao de login

Do While oBrowser.Busy

DoEvents

Loop

oBrowser.navigate (sURL & ("build.php?tt=2&id=39"))    ' navego até a pagina que quero ir

Do While oBrowser.Busy

DoEvents

Loop

Set HTMLDocu = oBrowser.document

HTMLDocu.all.t4.Value = "9"`